# If order confirmation email is sent then entry remove from database automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

i want to know, that
If order confirmation email is sent then entry remove from 
**core_email_queue**  Or
**core_email_queue_recipients**
database table automatically.

and if database table have entry inserted so what is meaning of that?,
email are sent or not?

In Email Sending, What is the Role Of CRON?
can CRON affect the order email sending process?

pls, explain me..
Thank You..

Comment: Yes CRON will affect the order email sending process. In magento 1.9 the transactional emails are sent through the queue system. In each cron it will send the emails in queue.

Comment: i have many entry in database , means that emails are not sent? now

Comment: I configure the Sales Emails as info@vibesaudio.com, Contacts as info@vibesaudio.com but email not sent